# Column slice pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the dummy DataFrame:

```
d = {'col_1': [1, 2], 'col_n_1': [3, 4], 'col_2': [2, 1], 'col_n_2': [6, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


   col_1    col_2   col_n_1   col_n_2
0      1        2         3         6
1      2        1         4         3
2      1        1         4         5
```

I am looking for a nice way to extract the values from `col_n_1` where `col_1 == 1` and `col_n_2` where `col_2 == 1`
in a new column that would look like:

```
new_col
      3
      3
    4,5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for get values by mask and then `join` columns together:

```
L = ['col_1','col_2']
L1 = ['col_n_1','col_n_2']
df['new'] = (df[L1].astype(str).where(df[L].eq(1).values, axis=1)
                  .apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), 1))
```

Solution if only 2 columns:

```
L = ['col_1','col_2']
L1 = ['col_n_1','col_n_2']
df1 = df[L1].astype(str).where(df[L].eq(1).values, axis=1)
df['new'] = (df1['col_n_1'] .fillna('') + ',' + df1['col_n_2'] .fillna('')).str.strip(',')
```

Or solution with add `,` and then `sum`, last remove trailing `,`:

```
df['new'] = (df[L1].astype(str).where(df[L].eq(1).values)
                  .add(', ')
                  .fillna('')
                  .sum(axis=1)
                  .str.strip(', '))
```

---

```
print (df)
   col_1  col_2  col_n_1  col_n_2  new
0      1      2        3        6    3
1      2      1        4        3    3
2      1      1        4        5  4,5
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrow the name list from Jez

```
df[L].eq(1).rename(columns=dict(zip(L,L1))).mul((df[L1].astype(str)+',')).sum(1).str[:-1]
Out[126]: 
0      3
1      3
2    4,5
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the `apply()` method and a lambda function. `apply()` with the `index` parameter set to `1` will call a given function on each row of the dataframe. So the only trouble is writing that function -- I think the best solution is to create a list containing either the row's `col_n_1` or `col_n_2`, both, or neither, then joining the list with commas. Like this:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join([str(row.col_n_1)] if row.col_1 == 1 else [] + [str(row.col_n_2)] if row.col_2 == 1 else []), axis = 1)
```

Comment: but then imagine there are like 1k columns